# Select checkbox by label-text from sorrounding label?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

following structure:

```
<label class="selectit">
    <input value="3" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[event_type][]" id="in-event_type-3">
     Workshops
</label>
```

I can easily do that to find out if the checkbox is checked …

```
if ( $('#in-event_type-3').attr('checked') ) {
```

Is there also some way to use a selector where I can put in "Workshops" to select the checkbox? The problem is that the `id` of the checkbox is generated dynamically and changes from time to time. The `label`-text "Workshops" however is set by me and I wonder if I can somehow write a selector that uses this "Workshops" string to select the checkbox?

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Is wrapping a checkbox by a label valid HTML?

Comment: @JeffSahol Not only is it valid, it's very good practice as it gives a much bigger hit area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `:contains` selector:

```
$(".selectit:contains('Workshops')").find(":checkbox").prop('checked');
```

Comment: This is it, thank you!  
@rest I can't change the html because it's the backend of wordpress. Only the label is set by me.

Answer (score 1):

Give your label a for attribute:

```
<label class="selectit" for="in-event_type-3">
```

edit: Apologies, didn't realize the ID changes from time to time.
You can also put some jQuery to find the input and then assign the for.
Like this:

```
$('input').each( function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('for', $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it impossible to add a class ?

after it's easier to select it ?

```
if($('.Workshops').is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can control your input to put a class on it (lets call it "workshop"), then it would be:

```
$(".workshop").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

So, everyone else has said to use a class - listen to them! It's much easier!

However, sometimes altering the HTML content is simply not an option.  In that case we would have to resort to some dirty work and look at all the text contained within the label elements to find the corresponding checkbox.

```
var selectedCheckboxes = [];
$.each($("#container > label"),function(index,elem){
  var labelText = $(elem).text();
  var testString = "Workshops";
  if (labelText.match(testString)){
    selectedCheckboxes = $(elem).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  }
});
```

I must warn you that this solution would work for the simple example that you gave, however if the markup is slightly more complicated (as in additional child elements with their own text content) then this method would have to get ALOT bigger and ALOT more complicated.

There is no inbuilt selector to match the textual content of elements in the HTML markup, and rightly so.  The textual content of elements should only be visual representation of data or information;  It should never contain identity information.  To identify an element and set is apart from its siblings or descendants, we use `id` and `class` attributes.  There are more that can be used but these are the basic building blocks.

One thing to note here is the behavior of jQuery's `.text()` function.  It will :

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, **including their descendants.**

<sup>Emphasis added</sup>

The `:contains()` selector has similar behavior with regard to descendants and has [already been covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124899/558021) in a previous answer.

On to a more *hands-on* and visual example of this limitation...

Given this minimalistic HTML  snippet :

```
<div id="matt">
  One
  <span>Two</span>
  <div> 
     <label>Three</label>
  </div>
  Four
</div>
```

A call to `$("#matt").text()` would result in :

> OneTwoThreeFour

All of the descendants textual content is included as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = $('input').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).parent('label').text())=='Workshops'?$(this):null;
});

var isChecked = $(element).attr('checked'); //true-false
```